# What is the name of this South India plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

Location: South India.

Month: June.

Branches of the tree:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1GMa.jpg]

Lower part of the Plant:

[image]

Plant's leaf:

[image]

Whole plant:

[image]

Comment: Hi Welcome to Bio.SE! Please upload all of your images using the url option of the image uploader. Simply adding links is dangerous because they might become nonworking and your question becomes unusable /unamswerable. Thanks!